# Fibonacci sequence multiplying

Tags: list, python-2.7, while-loop, sequence, fibonacci

I tried to make the fibonacci sequence with the following code:

```
def fibonacci(n): # write Fibonacci series up to n
    """Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a = 0
    b = 1
    the_list = []
    while n > len(the_list):
        the_list.append(a)
    #By saying a = b and b = a+b we define the
    #fibonacci sequence, since this is how the
    #fibonacci sequence works.
        a = b
        b = a+b
    print the_list
# Now call the function we just defined:
fibonacci(10)
```

As far as I know this code should do it but instead of giving me the fibonacci sequence its giving the following output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
```

So my fibonacci sequence is multiplying instead of working correcly. I have no idea why because i thought

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

should do the trick, if i look at my while loop the statements for this loop are also correct, so I just dont get it why i dont get the right output.

So if someone could explain me why this code is not working it would be highly appriciated

Comment: Think about what is happening on each iteration. `a` is being assigned `b`'s value, and then `b` is being set to `a` + `b`. Starting on the iteration where `b=1`, you will first set `a=1`, and then set `b = a + b = 1 + 1 = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating an exponential sequence because of a logic flaw. Based on your code:

```
Start:
a = 0
b = 1

1st iteration:
a = b = 1
b = a + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2

2nd iteration:
a = b = 2
b = a + 2 = 2 + 2 = 4
```

As you can see the fact that you set `a` before performing the `b` calculation causes your issue.

Instead you need would something like (to prove the point):

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp + a
```

A little extra math would eliminate the need for the extra variable:

```
b += a
a = b - a
```

But the easiest (and most pythonic) way would be:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```